# Android Studio login and registration app: register button working well but login button does nothing

Tags: mysql, android-studio

I have created an Android login and registration app using Android Studio 2.3.3 for MacBook Pro. The register button is working well and sending data to the MySQL database. But the login button is not doing anything even after clicking. Below are some of the codes.

Comment: Probably a typo, but you did not include any code.

Comment: How does someone include a code by the way?

Comment: For short one line code snippets encase the text in tildas which are normally above the tab key. For block code have a blank line after your last text then write/paste in your code but have each line preceded by four spaces. Both times you'll know you did it right if the text background gets darker.

Comment: For block formatting, paste your code into the edit box, select it, and click the `{}` formatting button.